# Customize CakePHP Controller's flash() method

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I need to customize CakePHP Controller's flash() method like this,

```
//$progressId variable is extra
//the error is customized method is not compatible with Controller::flash() method
public function flash($message, $url, $pause = 1, $progressIs, $layout = 'flash') {
    $this->autoRender = FALSE;
    $this->set('url', Router::url($url));
    $this->set('message', $message);
    $this->set('pause', $pause);
    $this->set('page_title', __('action result title'));
    $this->set('progress_is', $progressIs);
    $this->render(FALSE, $layout);
}
```

How to customize correctly?

Thank You,

Alireza

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the 'signature' of the custom (overridden) method is different from the original one.

When overriding a method, make sure that it stays compatible with the original one.

Imagine this example;

```
public function serveSandwich($person, $sandwich, $drink = null)
{
    find($person);
    serve($person, $sandwich);
    if ($drink) {
        serve($person, $drink);
    }
}
```

This works great, this method allows you to serve somebody a sandwich and (optionally) a drink, for example:

```
serveSandwich('motherinlaw', 'peanut butter', 'orange juice');
```

However, this function doesn't meet your requirements, you want to offer somebody a seat before serving the sandwich.

So you decide to override the method with your advanced method;

```
public function serveSandwich($person, $furniture, $sandwich, $drink = null)
{
    find($person);
    havePersonSitOn($person, $furniture);
    serve($person, $sandwich);
    if ($drink) {
        serve($person, $drink);
    }
}
```

For your next party, you hire Jeeves, who is qualified to serve sandwiches using CakePHP 2.3.

You ask Jeeves to serve your mother in law a peanut butter sandwich; He knows how to do that in CakePHP, so this happens:

```
serveSandwich('motherinlaw', 'peanut butter', 'orange juice');
```

However, Jeeves doesn't know of the incompatible override, so you'll end up with your Mother in law sitting on a Peanut Butter sandwich, having an Orange juice in her hand!

### How to do this properly

Basically, you can opt for two approaches;

#### Create a new method that calls the original one

```
public function seatAndServeSandwich($person, $furniture, $sandwich, $drink = null)
{
    havePersonSitOn($person, $furniture);
    $this->serveSandwich($person, $sandwich, $drink = null)
}
```

This is the preferred way; in order to make use of the advanced function, you *explicitly* call the new method, which, in its turn, calls the original method

In your case:

```
public function customflash($message, $url, $pause = 1, $progressIs, $layout = 'flash') {
    $this->set('progress_is', $progressIs);
    return $this->flash($message, $url, $pause, $layout);
}
```

#### Append the new argument at the end

This will also work, but *may* cause problems if future versions of CakePHP will add new arguments to the `flash` method;

```
public function flash($message, $url, $pause = 1, $layout = 'flash', $progressIs = null) {
    $this->set('progress_is', $progressIs);
    return parent::flash($message, $url, $pause, $layout);
}
```

The extra parameter will never be used by other controllers, because they don't know it exists, therefore causing no problems (as long as its not a required parameter).